# Error 403 Forbidden: angular@1.6.4

Tags: angularjs, npm, dependencies, package

I try to run a `npm install` on a project who have angular as a dependency and I get this error:

```
error 403 Forbidden: angular@1.6.4
```

Comment: Node version? Are you on your own network?

Comment: 6.11.3 , not on my own network

Comment: Could be due to a proxy/firewall exception then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It came from my `.npmrc` files where I had an old registry set. After I cleared that out, everything web good.